# whats the correct way of depicting a login on a use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

In a use case diagram if someone needs to log in before completing an action should it be

```
 O
--- --> (login) ---<<extends>>-- (do action) 
 |          \    
/ \          \
            <<extends>>
               \
             (another action)
```

or

```
 O  
---  --> (do action)  
 |   \            
/ \   \       
      (login)
```

or

```
 O  
--- --> (do action)  
 |          \    
/ \          \
            <<includes>>
               \
              (login)
```

or something different altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case is for showing WHAT will be done by WHOM and you can organize these what's and whom's in groups (organizations and subsystems). Do not try to express inner structure or sequence of actions, there are other diagrams for that.

Use `include` only if one action of user can include another action, again of a user. When that another action is called by the system itself, don't show it!

The same about `extends`.

As for `uses`, it is not a standard stereotype for Use Case diagram.

Notice, you shouldn't show that after the registration the user is automatically logged in - it is not information for Use Case Diagram level. Leave it in some text document an put it later into the State Machine diagram.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I didn't mean to put uses(meant includes). So I take it form this that login would be a separate use case? even if a precondition for another case is that the user must be logged in. Additionally is it normal practice to include notes to explain the steps a user takes when logging in ?

Comment: @user1652319 Yes, preconditions are STATES. These are to be solved on state machine diagram. Don't pollute the Use Case diagram with them.

Comment: @user1652319 As for how the dialogues user-comp go, put them in words, and as for diagrams, use Sequence diagrams for them. But mostly, state diagram will be enough.

Comment: @user1652319 Thank you too, and I congratulate you with your new privileges. Use them for better supporting answerers for your questions :-). We all should support the themes we are interested in, by supporting each other. (Of course, not for bad answers) –